# UnityScript If(var="this" OR "that"){//do something}

Tags: if-statement, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm not sure how to make the following code work:

```
if(response!==("usernamewrong" OR "passwordwrong")){
    print("login Wrong");
} else {
    //if anything else other than the two shows up into the response goes here
}
```

Comment: `if (response==="usernamewrong" || response==="passwordwrong"){`

Comment: is that not equal sign === ?

Comment: yes and no:  
http://www.impressivewebs.com/why-use-triple-equals-javascipt/ ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be explicit when doing multiple checks in a conditional:

```
if (response == "usernamewrong" || response == "passwordwrong")
```

Comment: but if its not equal to any of the two, Same?

Comment: Yes: `if (response != "usernamewrong" || response != "passwordwrong")`